# What is the benefit of resizing images with ImageMagick as opposed to CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick

So my ruby on rails app has functionality to allow users to upload pictures. I know that Active Storage can use ImageMagick to resize images like this

```
model.image.variant(resize: "100X100")
```

However, you can also do it in CSS like this:

```
<%= image_tag(rails_blob_url("file_name.jpg"), width: '100px', height: '100px') %>
```

Which one should you use? Should I use ImageMagick or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of the first approach is the size of the final files.

When you use imagemagick as the resizer, the final output of the file is an actual 100x100 file, which, let's say, weights 100KB. Then you send this file to the frontend which will be an asset that only weights 100KB.

On the other hand, if you resize it in the view only, the original asset will be rendered and then resized in the frontend, however the server and client will have to deal with a, let's say, 1MB file instead of a 100KB, which will impact performance of the app.

Answer (score 1):

CSS at best probably does linear interpolation when enlarging or shrinking. But ImageMagick has many advanced interpolation filters, not just pixel replicate or linear interpolation that can produce sharper results and/or less artifacts. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/